# No puedo mostrar un valor de un fichero yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Tengo un problema a la hora de obtener los valores de un fichero yml.

Estoy haciendo pruebas con un proyecto muy sencillo.

Mi lanzador de la aplicación contiene lo siguiente:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
            applicationContext.getBean(Runner.class).main(args);
        }   
    }

}
```

Mi `Runner` contiene lo siguiente:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.example.demo.util.Utils;

@Component
public class Runner {
    
    Utils utils = new Utils();
    @Value("${searchfiles.csv.path}")
    private String constant;
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(constant);
        utils.showConstant();

    }

}
```

En esta clase, el valor de `constant` lo recoge bien y se muestra correctamente.

El metodo de `Utils` al que se llama dentro, es el que no recoge el valor correctamente. Tiene el siguiente contenido:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Utils {

    @Value("${searchfiles.csv.path}")
    private String constant;
    
    public void showConstant() {
        System.out.println(constant);
    }
    
}
```

Dejo las pruebas en las siguiente imágenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me descuadra mucho porque tiene exactamente las mismas anotaciones. Es realmente en la clase de `Utils` donde tengo que recoger estos valores.

El proyecto se puede descargar desde aquí: https://toffeesha.re/c/JgmFcfeN

Comment: Una cosilla. Al invocar tú explicitamente el constructor de Utils, te estás saltando el mecanismo de inyección de dependencias de Spring para esa clase. Es decir, al poner `@Component` en Utils, Spring te va a crear un bean, una instancia A de esa clase. En esa instancia concreta es donde, empleando `@Value`, se está dando un valor a constant. Pero insisto, al invocar el contructor explicitamente, empleas una instancia B distinta de la generada por Spring de ese clase, donde `@Value` no tiene efecto. Prueba a quitar la inicialización explícita y anota utils en la clase Runner como `@Autowired`

Comment: Oh my god, estabas en lo cierto, he dejado de instanciar el objeto de la forma que tenía y le he puesto la anotación del ```@Autowired``` y está funcionando correctamente. No sé cómo no había caído... Si quieres poner la solución en modo respuesta en vez de en comentario, te la marcaré muy gustosamente como solución :)

Comment: Claro, es que no estaba 100% seguro y no tenía tiempo de probarlo, por eso he comentado en lugar de responder. :-)

Comment: Pues acertaste! He estado un par de días investigando el asunto, haciendo configuraciones en el pom y tal y nada... y resulta que era por eso. Me has alegrado la mañana!

Comment: Nada, hombre. Encantado de ayudar. Hoy por ti, mañana por mí. ;-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al invocar tú explicitamente el constructor de `Utils`, te estás saltando el mecanismo de inyección de dependencias de Spring para esa clase.

```
@Component
public class Runner {
    
    Utils utils = new Utils(); // Aquí NO hay inyección de dependencias

    @Value("${searchfiles.csv.path}")
    private String constant;
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(constant);
        utils.showConstant();

    }

}
```

Es decir, al poner `@Component` en `Utils`, Spring te va a crear un bean, una instancia A de esa clase. En esa instancia concreta es donde, empleando `@Value`, se está dando un valor a `constant`. Pero insisto, al invocar el contructor explicitamente, creas una instancia B distinta de la generada por Spring de esa clase, donde `@Value` no tiene efecto.

Prueba a quitar la inicialización explícita y anota `utils` en la clase `Runner` como `@Autowired`

```
@Component
public class Runner {
    
    @Autowired
    Utils utils;

    @Value("${searchfiles.csv.path}")
    private String constant;
    
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(constant);
        utils.showConstant();

    }

}
```